# Pycharm running unittest in verbose mode

Tags: python, class, pycharm, python-unittest, verbose

Is there a way to run unittests in pycharm in verbose mode. I am looking for a way to see the docstring in the test functions so that i can see some info of the ran test.

```
class KnownValues(unittest.TestCase):
    known_values = (
        ([1, 2],[[1, 2]]),
        ([1, 2, 3], [[1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]),
        ([1, 2, 3, 4],[[1, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4]]),
        ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5],[[1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]),
        ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],[[1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]),
              )

    def test_check(self):
        '''This should check is the function returning right'''
        for arg, result in self.known_values:
            print("Testing arg:{}".format(arg))
            assert program.lister(arg) == result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

It returns:

```
Testing started at 19:38 ч. ...
Testing arg:[1, 2]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I want to get:

```
test_check (__main__.KnownValues)
This should check is the function returning right ... Testing arg:[1, 2]
ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is to use the `setUp` method and call the `_testMethodDoc` attribute like this:

```
def setUp(self):
    print(self._testMethodDoc)
```

You can ofcourse make your own base class for your unittest that inherit from `unittest.TestCase`) but then if you want to override the `setUp` method later, you will have to call `super`. It is an option to make shorter code implementation:

```
class BaseUnitTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        print(self._testMethodDoc)


class KnownValues(BaseUnitTest):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(verbosity=2)
```